# How do I add a new attribute to an edge in networkx?

Tags: python, graph, attributes, networkx

**What I have:** a graph G imported in networkx with nodes and edges loaded by gml file.

**Problem**: How to add a new attribute to a selected edge E.

**What I want to do:** I want to add a new attribute 'type' for a particular edge E of my graph. Attention: the attribute 'type' doesn't exist for this edge E.

My code is:

```
  G.edge[id_source][id_target]['type']= value
```

But if I print all the edges of G, now I have n+1 edges; all the old edges of G, and a new edge p= (id_source, id_target, {'type'= value}). Furthermore, the old edge E (the one that I want modify) doesn't have the new attribute 'type'.

So my code have added a new edge (that I don't want).

**I want to update** the old one adding a new attribute that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You may have a networkx MultiGraph instead of a graph and in that case the attribute setting for edges is a little tricker.  (You can get a multigraph by loading a graph with more than one edge between nodes).  You may be corrupting the data structure by assigning the attribute
 `G.edge[id_source][id_target]['type']= value` when you need
 `G.edge[id_source][id_target][key]['type']= value`.

Here are examples of how it works differently for Graphs and MultiGraphs.

For the Graph case attributes work like this:

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.Graph()

In [3]: G.add_edge(1,2,color='red')

In [4]: G.edges(data=True)
Out[4]: [(1, 2, {'color': 'red'})]

In [5]: G.add_edge(1,2,color='blue')

In [6]: G.edges(data=True)
Out[6]: [(1, 2, {'color': 'blue'})]

In [7]: G[1][2]
Out[7]: {'color': 'blue'}

In [8]: G[1][2]['color']='green'

In [9]: G.edges(data=True)
Out[9]: [(1, 2, {'color': 'green'})]
```

With MultiGraphs there is an additional level of keys to keep track of the parallel edges so it works a little differently.  If you don't explicitly set a key MultiGraph.add_edge() will add a new edge with an internally chosen key (sequential integers).

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.MultiGraph()

In [3]: G.add_edge(1,2,color='red')

In [4]: G.edges(data=True)
Out[4]: [(1, 2, {'color': 'red'})]

In [5]: G.add_edge(1,2,color='blue')

In [6]: G.edges(data=True)
Out[6]: [(1, 2, {'color': 'red'}), (1, 2, {'color': 'blue'})]

In [7]: G.edges(data=True,keys=True)
Out[7]: [(1, 2, 0, {'color': 'red'}), (1, 2, 1, {'color': 'blue'})]

In [8]: G.add_edge(1,2,key=0,color='blue')

In [9]: G.edges(data=True,keys=True)
Out[9]: [(1, 2, 0, {'color': 'blue'}), (1, 2, 1, {'color': 'blue'})]

In [10]: G[1][2]
Out[10]: {0: {'color': 'blue'}, 1: {'color': 'blue'}}

In [11]: G[1][2][0]['color']='green'

In [12]: G.edges(data=True,keys=True)
Out[12]: [(1, 2, 0, {'color': 'green'}), (1, 2, 1, {'color': 'blue'})]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But in multigraph example when you add the edge you add also the attribute color. I need add a new attribute that doesn't exist when i have created the edge. For example after line 3 , how i Can add a second attribute to edge 1-2 ????

Comment: Sure just write G.add_edge(1,2,other='foo').  You might not want to use `type` since it is a reserved word in Python (though it will probably be OK to use like this).

Comment: But i tried G.add_edge(1,2, other='foo'). But it Adds a new one edge different by th first edge 1,2,color: red).  i want This : (1,2, color: red, other: foo). How Can i get This result?

Comment: So do you have a MultiGraph or a Graph object?  The approach is different as I explained in my answer.  Try type(G).

Comment: I have a multigraph. In fac ti have multiple edge between two nodes. Consider a single edge between (1,2) . Initially i add edge (1,2, color='red') . After i do some stuff and i want add a new attribute to edge (1,2). So for example i want add other='foo' to (1,2) . The result is: (1,2, color='red', other='foo' ). Ok????

Comment: You need to specify a key too for MultiGraphs (see my example).  If you don't set a key at creation you will get a automatically generated integer key.  See G.edges(keys=True).

Comment: I wrote `key_id = H[id_source][id_target]['key']` and then `H.add_edge(id_source,id_target,key=key_id,type='normal')`  But when i compile i get this error:  `key_id = H[id_source][id_target]['key']
KeyError: 'key'` I don't set the key for each edge, so it automatically set a integer (i printed it). How i can get a key attribute of a specif edge?

Answer (score 3):

I don't quite understand why you want add an attribute to only one edge, instead you can add an attribute to all edges, then you give the `the wanted value` to your specific edge.

Networkx has a method called `set_edge_attributes` can add an edge attributes to all edges, for example

```
    G = nx.path_graph(3)
    bb = nx.edge_betweenness_centrality(G, normalized=False)
    nx.set_edge_attributes(G, 'betweenness', bb)
    G[1][2]['betweenness']
```

Output:    2.0

Comment: You should answer the actual question asked, not a different question that you can easily answer by copying from the documentation.  This method can actually be adapted to update just one edge (by specifying the `bb` dictionary for that specific edge), but that's not what you offered as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer below by Xin-Feng Li works, just note that the arguments for `values` and `name` switched between Networkx v1.x (when the answer was originally written) and Networkx v2.x. For v2.x, the code is:

```
G = nx.path_graph(3)
bb = nx.edge_betweenness_centrality(G, normalized=False)
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, bb, 'betweenness')
G[1][2]['betweenness']
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution added from OP's question:

> Thanks to Aric and some tricks I solved my problem:
>
> ```
> def add_attribute_to_edge(H,id_node_source,id_node_target,new_attr,value_attr):
>
>       keydict =H[id_node_source][id_node_target]
>       key=len(keydict)
>       for k in keydict:
>           if 'type' not in H.edge[id_source][id_target][k]:
>              H.add_edge(id_node_source,id_node_target,key=k, new_attr= value_attr)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a better and short way to add new attributes to an existing edge in a graph:

```
>>> for itr in G.edges_iter(None, True, True):
        itr

(0, 1, {})
(0, 2, {'edge': (0, 2)})
(0, 3, {})
(0, 4, {})
(1, 2, {})
(1, 3, {})
(2, 3, {})
(2, 4, {})
(3, 4, {})
>>> G[0][1].update(edge=(0,1))      #This will add 'edge'=(0,1) dict item to edge(0,1)
>>> for itr in G.edges_iter(None, True, True):
        itr


(0, 1, {'edge': (0, 1)})
(0, 2, {'edge': (0, 2)})
(0, 3, {})
(0, 4, {})
(1, 2, {})
(1, 3, {})
(2, 3, {})
(2, 4, {})
(3, 4, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   nx.set_edge_attributes(
      G,
      {
         (id_source, id_target): {
            'type1': value1,
            'type2': value2,
            'type3': value3
            }
      }
  )
```