# How to define multiple attributes for an edge in multi Digraph

Tags: python, networkx

I have a graph with four nodes with two directional edges betweeen each node (a to b and b to a), so I use a multi Digraph. The graph already has the 'weight' attribute defined by default which for my case represent the capacity of each edge for traffic flow. I need to define two more attributes for each edge, let's say tcv1 and tcv2.

Being a beginner with Python and networkx I am not able to figure this out. Some google search took me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691442/add-new-attribute-to-an-edge-in-networkx) but I could not use it correctly.

```
add_attribute_to_edge(router_matrix, tmp_path[0][0], tmp_path[0][1], 'tcv1', traffic_cv[0])
```

I used code above where router_matrix is graph, tmp_path[x][x] will represent a node name like 'a' or 'b', tcv1 is the attribute and traffic_cv[0] in code will be an integer calculated. Printing tcv1 only gives {}.

Can someone suggest a solution or point out where I go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `add_edge` function  to add new attributes to existing edges in a `MultiDiGraph`, but you need to watch out for the `key` keyword (its value needs to be 0).

In my example I add the `tcv1` attribute the first "a" -> "b" edge (I use your variable names and my example graph created with `add_edges_from`):

```
import networkx as nx

router_matrix = nx.MultiDiGraph()

# add two weighted edges ("a" -> "b" and "b" -> "a")
router_matrix.add_edges_from([
    ("a", "b", {"weight": 0.5}),
    ("b", "a", {"weight": 0.99})
    ])

# print list of edges with all data
print(router_matrix.edges(data=True))

tmp_path = [["a", "b"], ["b", "a"]]
traffic_cv = [42, 66]

# add "tcv1" for only the first edge of tmp_path
router_matrix.add_edge(tmp_path[0][0], tmp_path[0][1], key=0, tcv1=traffic_cv[0])

print(router_matrix.edges(data=True))
```

To add `tcv1` to all edges, you could use `router_matrix.edges()` to iterate trough all edges (note that here I use the `G[src_node][dest_node][key][attribute]` syntax instead of `add_edge`):

```
# add new attribute to all edges
counter = 0
for src, dest in router_matrix.edges():
    router_matrix[src][dest][0]['tcv1'] = traffic_cv[counter]
    counter += 1

print(router_matrix.edges(data=True))
```