# Matplotlib and Networkx - drawing a self loop node

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, draw, networkx

I have this function and I want to draw a self loop. How can I do that?
The edge exists but I think it's just a point in this exemple is (1,1) and I couldn't add the name of nodes. 
My goal is from adjacency matrix draw a graph. Is there there is better way to do this?

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch, Circle
import numpy as np

def draw_network(G,pos,ax,sg=None):

    for n in G:
        c=Circle(pos[n],radius=0.05,alpha=0.7)
        ax.add_patch(c)
        G.node[n]['patch']=c
        x,y=pos[n]
    seen={}
    for (u,v,d) in G.edges(data=True):
        n1=G.node[u]['patch']
        n2=G.node[v]['patch']
        rad=0.1
        if (u,v) in seen:
            rad=seen.get((u,v))
            rad=(rad+np.sign(rad)*0.1)*-1
        alpha=0.5
        color='k'

        e = FancyArrowPatch(n1.center,n2.center,patchA=n1,patchB=n2,
                            arrowstyle='-|>',
                            connectionstyle='arc3,rad=%s'%rad,
                            mutation_scale=10.0,
                            lw=2,
                            alpha=alpha,
                            color=color)
        seen[(u,v)]=rad
        ax.add_patch(e)
    return e


G=nx.MultiDiGraph([(1,2),(1,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(2,4),
                (1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(2,4)]
                )

pos=nx.spring_layout(G)
ax=plt.gca()
draw_network(G,pos,ax)
ax.autoscale()
plt.axis('equal')
plt.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that your approach is quite advanced a use of matplotlib, but I would still recommend using a specialized graph plotting library ([as does the networkx documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.11/reference/drawing.html)).  As graphs get bigger, more problems arise -- but problems that have already been solved in those libraries.

A "go-to" option is [graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/gallery/), which handles drawing multi-graphs reasonably well.  You can write dot files from networkx graphs, and then use one of the graph drawing tools (e.g. dot, neato, etc).

Here is an example, building on [graph attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39662097) and [multigraph edge attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26694158):

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import to_agraph 

# define the graph as per your question
G=nx.MultiDiGraph([(1,2),(1,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(2,4), 
    (1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(2,4)])

# add graphviz layout options (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39662097)
G.graph['edge'] = {'arrowsize': '0.6', 'splines': 'curved'}
G.graph['graph'] = {'scale': '3'}
                                                                                
# adding attributes to edges in multigraphs is more complicated but see
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/26694158                    
G[1][1][0]['color']='red'
                                                                                
A = to_agraph(G) 
A.layout('dot')                                                                 
A.draw('multi.png')
```

[image: multi-graph with self loops]

Note that you can also easily invoke the drawing from within an ipython shell:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14945560

Comment: Can you plot this graph with MattPlotLib as well?

Comment: For Jupyterlab, `Image(A.draw(format='png'))` prints the graph _inline_ to the same browser session. Need to import `Image` through: `from IPython.display import Image`.