# How to draw multiple edges with Networkx

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I recently saw this answer: [Matplotlib and Networkx - drawing a self loop node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340520/matplotlib-and-networkx-drawing-a-self-loop-node)

And tried the code for drawing an undirected multigraph:

```
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import to_agraph 
G = nx.MultiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([('A','C'),('A','C'),('A','C'), ('C', 'C'), ('B', 'C'), ('A', 'B')])
G.graph['edge'] = {'splines': 'curved'}
G.graph['graph'] = {'scale': '3'}
A = to_agraph(G) 
A.layout('dot')                                                                 
A.draw('images/multigraph_example.png')
```

However, the result from the code is this:

[image]

It only shows one edge from `A` to `C`. How can I make it show the three edges?

Comment: Voting to close as not reproducible. Running your code verbatim shows this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGgxu.png  I'm using networkx v2.4 and pygraphviz 1.5.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to draw multigraph in networkx using matplotlib or graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943439/how-to-draw-multigraph-in-networkx-using-matplotlib-or-graphviz)

Comment: @wim it's weird... I am also using those versions of networkx and pygraphviz and still get the graph shown.